# Default column width for text data in a table

Tags: layout, tables

I'm designing an application with a data table. The data is backed by a C-style string (that is to say, a `char` array) so I know the maximum theoretical width using my proportionally-spaced typeface.

For example, assume that a string's length can't be greater than 32 characters. Naively, I can say that since "W" is the widest character, the maximum theoretical column width is 32 times the width of "W". But this will pretty much never happen, and if I make my column as wide as 32 "W"'s there'll be a lot of wasted space on average. On the other hand, it's not the end of the world if a string runs long and is truncated; I just want the vast majority of strings to be represented in their entirety.

Is there a back-of-the-envelope calculation for estimating the ideal default column width?

Comment: Simply use an existing table that adjusts its column widths depending on what the width of the widest item is in each column.

Comment: @AndroidHustle: The table is virtualized and can have over 100,000 items. Unfortunately that's not an option in this case.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a calculation that would be better suited on stackoverflow.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If (as you say) truncation is acceptable, then the question is more about:

- what you expect the column width do be most of the time
- what other columns also have to fit next to it
- how wide the expected screen resolution will be
- how much can be truncated without being a problem

These are all things that **require a subjective evaluation**, which you have to make and then test.